# Requests.get API data retrieval

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

*Using Python 3.5.3 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit) on Windows 10*

The code below returns:

```
company_id,indicator_id
```

Please help me convert this request to the actual stock data provided by the link. The token in this code is not designated to any particular person, so it's fine to run it.

```
import requests

company_id = '320193,1418091'

url = 'https://api.usfundamentals.com/v1/indicators/xbrl?companies={{company_id}}&indicators=NetIncomeLoss&frequency=y&period_type=end_date&token=b-KCkr7xnSkmkhPm5N0iTA'


f = requests.get(url)

print (f.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`company_id` in `url` is not getting evaluated. It works using [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

```
import requests
company_id = '320193,1418091'

url = 'https://api.usfundamentals.com/v1/indicators/xbrl?companies={0}&indicators=NetIncomeLoss&frequency=y&period_type=end_date&token=b-KCkr7xnSkmkhPm5N0iTA'.format(company_id)

f = requests.get(url)

print (f.text)
```